# Ramanujan's theta functions and hook lengths?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, partitions

Given an integer partition $\lambda\vdash n$ of $n$, one may associate a Young diagram $Y(\lambda)$ to it followed by a computation of hook length $h_{\square}$ for each cell $\square=(i,j)$ in $Y(\lambda)$. Denote the total sum of these numbers by $\sum_{\lambda}:=\sum_{\square\in Y}h_{\square}$.

For example, if $\lambda=(3,2,2)$ then the hook lengths are found as $\{5,4,1,3,2,2,1\}$ and also $\sum_{\lambda}=18$.

I was playing around with such numbers by introducing the sum $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}(-1)^{\sum_{\lambda}}$. Things took a nice turn to accumulate some evidence for which I ask:

> **QUESTION.** Is this true?
> $$\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}(-1)^{\sum_{\lambda}}\right)\cdot (-q)^n
> =\prod_{k\geq1}\frac{1+q^{2k-1}}{(1-q^{4k})(1+q^{4k-2})^2}.$$

**Remark.** A quick search for these coefficients [lead to this OEIS entry](https://oeis.org/A085261) and Ramanujan's $\theta$-functions.

Comment: I mentioned in a previous question of yours that this can be deduced from an identity of Boulet (specialize further to q=-1 from that post). https://mathoverflow.net/a/389183/2384

Comment: (That should have been x=-1 in my comment above but I can no longer edit)

Comment: Oh, that's true and I forgot to check back. It brings about another question. Consider $A(q;x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}x^{\sum_{\lambda}}\right)q^n$ from above and $B(q;x)=\sum_{n\geq0}\left(\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}x^{\sum_{(i,j)\in\lambda}(-1)^{i+j}h_{i,j}}\right)q^n$ from the link you pulled. Your answer showed a generating function for $B(q;x)$. Can the same argument yield a generating function for $A(q;x)$? Notice these functions agree at $x=-1$ but not always.